# The Performance is lower after removing The Laptop battery

Tags: laptop, performance, battery, lenovo-laptop, low-power

I use a Lenovo E560 with following components:
Intel Core i5-6200u
Intel HD graphics 520
AMD Radeon R7 M370
for playing Overwatch. 
I spent a lot of time in switching the graphics from Intel HD to M370. Now I'm able to play with around 50 FPS.
But after removing the battery the FPS got down to  around 15 fps. After some researches I found out that I can deactivate Battery Booster in The Nvidia driver but i have a AMD graphics Card.In The AMD driver I changed already from maximum battery Life to Maximum Performance. My question: Is there a option to deactivate the "battery boost"?

Comment: There is nothing analogous to battery boost for AMD. What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Peak performance is not possible without a battery because the inductance of the power cord is too high -- only a battery can supply the sharp current peaks required.

Comment: When you're taking out the battery, is the power plan setting being changed by chance? When I used to play games on a laptop I'd notice a very big difference between the "balanced" setting and the "high performance" setting.

Comment: maybe the power supply can't provide all required power and uses the battery and when it is removed it must trottle the GPU speed and may cause the perf issue

Comment: Yes this is obviously the truth, on the power supply is written that it can output 20V and 3,25A. that would be corresponds to (20V*3,25A=65W) 65 watts. The TDP-up of the CPU is 25 watts and The TDP of the Graphics Card is 35 watts. 25W+35W=60W
There are only 5 watts left for other components. Thanks for all the answers